# docx4j restart numbering bullets with XHTMLImporterIMPL

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm using XHTMLImporterIMPL to add a HTML-Fragment to a Word-Document. As soon as there is a numbered or unnumbered list within this HTML-Fragment, the Heading numbering is incremented. But I would like to have it restarted at 1 independent of the Heading-Numbering. 
I have tried to add a NumberingDefinitionsPart before adding the HTML-Fragment, with no success.